# Custom Data Formatting in jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a jQuery autocomplete script which gets its data from a database (Oracle).
It works fine, but I want to display the data differently.

I looked in http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data as example. Somehow I don't get it to work. I'm basically trying to do the same as in the example (displaying a description along with the item), but with a remote data source.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#id').val("");
$('#value').val("");
$('#desc').val("");

            $("#value").autocomplete({
                source: "states.php",
                minLength: 1,

                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $('#id').val(ui.item.id);
                    $('#value').val(ui.item.value);
                    $('#desc').val(ui.item.desc);
                }
            });
             .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
             return $( "<li>" )
             .append( "<a>" + item.value + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
             .appendTo( ul );
};
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>"  method="post">
<p class="ui-widget">
<input type="text" id="value"  name="value" />
<input type="text" id="desc" name="desc" />
<input type="text" id="id" name="id" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove the .data block my autocomplete works fine. But of course without the proper formatting.

```
             .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
             return $( "<li>" )
             .append( "<a>" + item.value + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
             .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Not sure if it's just a pasting error, but the code in your question has a syntax error. There's a semicolon (`;`) after the call to `autocomplete()`, but then you follow it with `.data()`. Remove the semicolon.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thank you so much!